# Can I import from node_modules of a module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, yarnpkg

I'm not that great at JS/TS but I'm helping run a build system. I have a bit of code that was submitted, and I'm not sure if I should alter the build system or kick it back to the developer.

The code looks like this...

```
import * as googleAuth from "googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library"
```

When I run `yarn install` the various modules are installed properly in `./node_modules/` including `googleapis` and `google-auth-library`. When I run `yarn build` I get something like this:

```
yarn run v1.19.1
$ rm -rf lib; ./node_modules/.bin/tsc -d -p tsconfig.npm.json
Error: src/foo/bar/common/oauth_helper.ts(3,29): error TS[23]: Cannot find module 'googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

When I test this out locally, I can make the error go away by doing `cd ./node_modules/googleapis && yarn install` but that installs a second set of all the modules needed there.

Is there something that I'm missing or should I tell the developer that he needs to import directly from `goggle-auth-library`. Furthermore if the developer is referencing this module explicitly I feel like he should list it as a dependency in `package.json`, not get it implicitly.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to directly install `google-auth-library` instead of going through the node_modules of another package.

This might be risky because lets says in future `googleapis` package updates and for some reason removes dependency on `google-auth-library` this will break your app.